# Express route functions not hoisted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

Could someone please explain to me why my Express routes are not hoisted?  I'm constantly seeing the following error thrown:

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware functions');
```

The following file **does not** produce the error:

```
var express        = require('express'),
    router         = express.Router()

var loadWidget = function (req, res, next) {

    req.widget = { text: 'Widget' };

    return next();
};

var sendWidget = function (req, res, next) {

    return res.status(200).send(req.widget);
};

router.use(loadWidget);

router.get('/', sendWidget);

module.exports = router;
```

However, changing the order of the methods, as in the file below, **does** throw the error:

```
var express        = require('express'),
    router         = express.Router()

router.use(loadWidget);

router.get('/', sendWidget);

var loadWidget = function (req, res, next) {

    req.widget = { text: 'Widget' };

    return next();
};

var sendWidget = function (req, res, next) {

    return res.status(200).send(req.widget);
};

module.exports = router;
```

I would like to have my file with the operations at the head of the file (`use`, `get`, `post`, etc.) with the actual bodies of the functions below.

On a side note, the error is thrown when I first invoke the app.  Sending `rs` with nodemon does not throw the error:

**Causes error:**

```
NODE_APP='app01' nodemon ./server/server
```

**No error:**

```
rs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations are hoisted in javascript but function expressions are not. Function expression is:

```
var fn = function() {};
```

And function declration:

```
function fn() {};
```

Comment: I have been using function expressions to help me identify async methods and functions for sync.  Guess I should probably just append "Sync" and assume everything else will be async.

Comment: @G.Deward "Sync" postfix is definitely better approach how to distinguish between sync and async functions :-)